# how to pass text box value to java script after leaving from text box?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html><body>
<input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" />
<input type="button" value="Edit"
    onClick="edit(document.getElementById('t1').value)" />
<div id="div1" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" value="2" />
</div>

<script>
    function edit() {

        x = document.getElementById('t1').value;
        if (x == "1234") {
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
            alert(x);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
            alert(x);
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here i passed the value of text box t1 to script on click of button to disable the div, but i dont want to have button here, instead when am leaving from text box (after entering value) i have to call script from text box itself. but it needs pass the all entered value at text box.

like,

```
   <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" onclick="edit(document.getElementById('t1').value);" />
```

please help? i want it in javascript not jquery? please guide me.

Comment: `onblur` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Comment: use `onblur` http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/w7dfr9qx/

Comment: thanks alot onblur met my need... dont know reason for down rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger an `onblur` event on the text box.

When the focus moves out of the text box, call the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this,

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" />
    <div id="div1" style="display: none">
         <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" value="2" />
    </div>

    <script>
         var x = document.getElementById("t1");  
         x.addEventListener("blur", edit, true);          

         function edit() {

         //do wat ever you want

          }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope, It helps...